# How to use grep function in eclipse C IDE (ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, grep, wc

I have a file with a couple of lines and in each one there is process id and its generation.
I need to print how many processes there are in each generation and do it with only one loop and have to do it with grep and wc function but can't find how to use grep in my IDE and not as a terminal function.
I saw it should be something like:

```
grep -o '\<WORD\>' | wc -l
```

but it's not something I can write in IDE..

Any ideas?

Comment: All IDE's I know of have some kind of "find" or "search" funcitonality, that can look through either the current file, all the files in the project, or an arbitrary directory.

Comment: I guess there are but I have to use grep or wc..I think it's also the onlt way to do it with only one loop

Comment: @royroy That can be done easily via _File Search_ (Ctrl+H) in Eclipse: the number of matches are shown in the _Search_ result view at the top and per file.